# Using FragmentManager to show dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

In Big Nerd Ranch's Android Programming, it says:

> When using an AlertDialog, it is a good idea to wrap it in an instance
>   of DialogFragment, a subclass of Fragment. It is possible to display
>   an AlertDialog without a DialogFragment, but it is not recommended.
>   Having the dialog managed by the FragmentManager gives you more
>   options for presenting the dialog.

What sort of options does using FragmentManager give you?

Comment: The primary reason for a `DialogFragment` is so it will be reopened after a configuration change (e.g., screen rotation). I do not know off the top of my head what the Big Nerd Ranch folk might have been referring to with respect to "options", though.

Comment: Yes Bid Nerd did mention rotation after this paragraph.  Curious what sort of sorts for presenting are they referring to here?